# Get tomorrows date from the webpage

Tags: php

What is a php function that i can make call tomorrows date formatted like this? `02/04/2014`

So if im looking at the website on 2/3/2014 it will show `02/04/2014`

If i look at it on 2/15/2014 it will show `2/16/2014`

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add using `strtotime()` / `date()` functions:

```
echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+1 day'));
```

**Update**

You can also do it using PHP's DateTime and DateInterval classes:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add('P1D');
echo $date->format('m/d/Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work ..

```
<?php
function tomorrow()
{$date = date('m/d/Y');
 sleep(24*60*60);
 return $date;}
 echo tomorrow();
?>
```